# tSQLt SpyProcedure with Output Parameters

Tags: tsqlt

I am attempting to spy a procedure with an output parameter. This procedure has two parameters, one input parameter and one output parameter.

The input parameter has a default value of NULL.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spExampleProcedure
    @INPUTPARAM DATETIME = NULL,
    @OUTPUTPARAM INT = NULL OUTPUT
AS
....
```

I'm attempting to test a procedure that is calling spExampleProcedure. spExampleProcedure is called multiple times with a different @INPUTPARAM. I want to check that param and return a different value based on the input. (A more advanced sort of mock.)

```
EXEC tSQLt.SpyProcedure 'dbo.spExampleProcedure', 
    'SET @OUTPUTPARAM = CASE WHEN @INPUTPARAM IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END'
```

This is not working. I would really like to be able to fake/spy a procedure like I do a function because It would really help when a stored procedure is called multiple times.

An option that I've considered is converting my spExampleProcedure to a Function but that would only avoid my issue instead. Looking at spy procedure, I see no reason why my setup should not be working beside maybe the fake procedure it creates might not have a default value of null.

Comment: tSQLt preserves `OUTPUT` parameters when spying a procedure, and setting their value works. That means, likely the problem you are encountering is somewhere else.

Could you post your entire test case, please?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I began to compile my test case to provide to you and While doing so, I noticed the source of the problem. My stored procedure was using a faked table and I was not inserting a value into this table. So when the procedure was called, that value was null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted example should work as pointed out by Sebastian Meine. I wanted to elaborate on why my test was not working in case that ends up helping somebody else.

My issue was related to my test data setup.

Consider:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spExampleProcedure
    @INPUTPARAM DATETIME = NULL,
    @OUTPUTPARAM INT = NULL OUTPUT
AS
....
```

And

```
EXEC tSQLt.SpyProcedure 'dbo.spExampleProcedure', 
    'SET @OUTPUTPARAM = CASE WHEN @INPUTPARAM IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END'
```

Procedure Under Test:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spExampleProcedureUnderTest
        @ID INT
    AS
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @EXAMPLEVAR DATETIME, @OUTPUT
        SELECT @EXAMPLEVAR = VAR FROM ExampleTable WHERE ID = @ID

        EXEC spExampleProcedure @OUTPUTPARAM = @OUTPUT OUTPUT
        EXEC spExampleProcedure @EXAMPLEVAR, @OUTPUT OUTPUT
        ...
```

My Test Procedure was faking ExampleTable but not putting a value in for VAR.

```
EXEC tSQLt.FakeTable 'dbo.ExampleTable'
INSERT INTO ExampleTable (ID) VALUES (1)
EXEC tSQLt.SpyProcedure 'dbo.spExampleProcedure', 
        'SET @OUTPUTPARAM = CASE WHEN @INPUTPARAM IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END'
EXEC spExampleProvedureUnderTest 1
```

Instead of

```
EXEC tSQLt.FakeTable 'dbo.ExampleTable'
INSERT INTO ExampleTable (ID, VAR) VALUES (1, '2018-06-01')
EXEC tSQLt.SpyProcedure 'dbo.spExampleProcedure', 
        'SET @OUTPUTPARAM = CASE WHEN @INPUTPARAM IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END'
EXEC spExampleProvedureUnderTest 1
```

EMPHASIS ON line 2 of each. Notice that I added a value in my insert.

Effectively, my spied Procedure was being called both times with NULL. BECAREFUL with data coming from Faked Tables. Faked tables remove constraints so it's easy to put a null into a table that would otherwise not allow it.